# How to submit more than one Bootstrap modal values into db using ajax post request in laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to insert the modal values by serializing those form values and trying to insert into it. But it's not working.

SCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

     $("#priceSave").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //var form1=$("#formprice").serialize();
   var data = $('form').serialize();
   $.ajax({
  url:'addPriceDetails/{{$dataId}}',
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response.SKUID);
      /*$("#skuid").append(response.SKUID);
      $("#mrp").append(response.MRP);
      $("#lstatus").append(response.listingStatus);
      $("#selprice").append(response.sellingPrice);*/

        //alert(response.SKUID);
      }
     });
     });
    $("#descSave").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var form2=$("#formdescription").serialize();
    //var data = $('form').serialize();
      $.ajax({
     url:'addPriceDetails/{{$dataId}}',
    type: "post",
    data: form2,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {


        alert(response);
    }
    });
    });
    });
   </script>
```

This is what I have tried.But I have some doubts with the commented lines.

Controller code:

```
 public function addPriceDetails(Request $formprice,$dataId)
{
$priceInfo = new priceModel ;
$priceInfo->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
$priceInfo->productId=$this->getproductId();
$priceInfo->SKUID=$formprice->input('skuid');
$priceInfo->listingStatus =$formprice->input('listingStatus');
$priceInfo->MRP =$formprice->input('mrp');
$priceInfo->sellingPrice=$formprice->input('selprice');
$priceInfo->fulfillmentBy =$formprice->input('fulfillment');
$priceInfo->procurementType =$formprice->input('procurementType');
$priceInfo->procurementSLA =$formprice->input('sla');
$priceInfo->stock =$formprice->input('stock');
$priceInfo->localDelCharge =$formprice->input('local');
$priceInfo->zonalDelCharge =$formprice->input('zonal');
$priceInfo->nationalDelCharge=$formprice->input('national');
$priceInfo->packWeight =$formprice->input('weight');
$priceInfo->packLength =$formprice->input('length');
$priceInfo->packBreadth =$formprice->input('breadth');
$priceInfo->packHeight =$formprice->input('height');
$priceInfo->HSN =$formprice->input('hsn');
$priceInfo->save();


$description=new descriptionModel;
$description->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
$description->productDescriptionId=$this->getproductDescriptionId();
$description->modelName=$formdescription->input('mname');
$description->Height=$formdescription->input('height');
$description->Weight=$formdescription->input('weight');
$description->Depth=$formdescription->input('depth');
$description->Width =$formdescription->input('width');
$description->Type =$formdescription->input('type');
$description->Character=$formdescription->input('character');
$description->batteryType=$formdescription->input('batteryType');
$description->salesPackage =$formdescription->input('package');
$description->skillSet =$formdescription->input('skillSet');
$description->Colour=$formdescription->input('colour');
$description->Material =$formdescription->input('material');
$description->maxAge=$formdescription->input('maxage');
$description->minAge =$formdescription->input('minage');
$description->batteryNos =$formdescription->input('batteryNos');
$description->batteryOperated=$formdescription-
>input('batteryOperated');
$description->rechargable=$formdescription->input('rechargable');

$description->save();


return response()->json([
    'SKUID'    => $priceInfo->SKUID,
]);
}
```

This is my controller code.Here I am trying to get the form values from both the modals.

Comment: What error are you getting in console?

Comment: No errors were displayed on the console.But its not saving to the db

Comment: helloo anyoneee???

Comment: Show us what you have written in your controller.

Comment: ` public function addPriceDetails(Request $formprice,$dataId)
   {
    $priceInfo = new priceModel ;
    $priceInfo->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
    $priceInfo->save();
    $description=new descriptionModel;
    $description->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
    $description->rechargable=$formdescription->input('rechargable');
    $description->save();


    return response()->json([
        'SKUID'    => $priceInfo->SKUID,
  
    ]);
}
`

Comment: This is my controller code.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post in comment.

Comment: Also show the html code of both the forms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755699/how-to-insert-multiple-formbootstrap-modal-values-into-database-using-ajax-pos

Comment: The above link gives more details on my issue

Comment: Is you page getting refreshed after you click on save button?

Comment: yes,the page gets refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Do these changes first -

1. Add `id` selector to your form.

<form name='formprice' id='formPrice'>

<form name="formdescription" id="formdescription">

2. Change input `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

3.In your ajax call user your id selector to serialize the form.

```
var form1 = $('#formPrice').serialize();

var form2=$("#formdescription").serialize();
```

4. Print all the post variables in your controller method. Once you get the request parameter it should easier for you to do the rest.

Comment: The main problem was, you used input type as submit. When you use submit page will refresh and ajax call will not execute. So once you change to button check you console first and be sure that ajax call is happening to correct route.